# Windows authentication of added application not working

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis

I have an intranet site hosted on Windows Server 2012 R2 and it works perfectly.  I have several applications set up on the same site with a mix of MVC and ASP Forms.  But for some reason, one site will not authenticate mobile devices or certain browsers of non-domain computers.

Both IOS and Android devices using Chrome or the default browser on the Android devices or Safari on the IOS Devices.  Neither of them even challenge for a username and password.

I have tried across both devices to clear all saved passwords and starting clean, but it still results in a 401 unauthorized page with no challenge.

On desktops, this site works on Domain computers with no challenge as expected, on non-domain computers however it's hit and miss depending on the browser.  Chrome and IE seem to work while Firefox doesn't.  Firefox displays the same behavior of authenticating to the root site but not even challenging the sub-application.  Note: firefox's behavior is  consistent across domain and non-domain computers alike.

I have tried combing through the web.config and IIS settings of each site and the only thing I can find that is different is I am using a different application pool, This particular site needed additional permissions so I have a pool with a new Identity.

One more point, while debugging the site on my dev machine, I can get all of the devices and browsers to authenticate, it's only when deployed to the server where this issues happens.

Edit:  I have done just a little more debugging and created a new application pointed at the same folder and it works.  As of this time, I am not sure what the issue is with the old application but starting over seems to have worked.

Comment: Have you enabled basic authentication? Not all browsers or devices can authenticate using NTLM authentication. Some can only work sending the password clear text without NTLM. Additionally, check if there is a proxy the devices need to go through. Some proxies can affect the capability for NTLM authentication if the device supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Authentication is comprised of **Kerberos** and **NTLM**.

KERBEROS in **INTRANET** only as the client needs access to Domain Controller and you do not want to expose your DC on Internet.
NTLM on the other hand is not supported by many proxies and hence it will work for some and not for others.

At the same time, there is some client dependency. The client should also support Windows Authentication. AFAIK, Internet Explorer is the only browser that provides first class support for Windows Auth.

Conclusion, if your app needs to communicate on Internet, you should not use Windows Authentication.

My recommendation would be to use other authentication mechanisms like:

- BASIC AUTH with SSL
- OAUTH like Facebook/Google etc